# Is there a way to use Map<K, V> as projection type in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a use case where the query looks like this:

```
SELECT SCHOLAR_ID ,COUNT(sja.JOB_DESC_ID) FROM SCHOLAR_JOB_APPLICATION sja WHERE sja.JOB_STATUS = 'SELECTED'
GROUP BY (sja.SCHOLAR_ID)
```

and when I am executing this query it returns the scholar_id and the count of job_desc_id as two columns where the first column is unique. So I have to implement the same in JPA and I thought of using Map<K, V> in java. But it seems to be the map is not getting populated and I am getting empty results.

```
@Query("select sja.scholar.id, count(sja.jobDescription.id) from ScholarJobApplication sja " +
            "where sja.jobStatus='SELECTED' " +
            "group by (sja.scholar.id)")
    Map<String, Integer> countScholarJobApplicationsInJobStatusSelected();
```

I have tried using List<Map<K, V>> which is working but can I use only Map?